# Dynamically created plots do not alternate with section headers in Quarto

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, quarto, dynamic-reports

Currently, I am writing a Quarto Markdown document with an HTML output. In this document I want to show several plots. Each plot should be within an own section in order to facilitate navigation. As I want to reduce boilerplate I create the plots dynamically.
Now, the section headers appear one after another while the plots all appear at the end of the section.

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| label: fig-attr-in-time
#| fig-cap: "Attribute in time"
#| results: "asis"
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
data_files = c(
  "test1",
  "test2",
  "test3"
)
set.seed(176)
test1 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))
test2 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))
test3 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))

print_attr_plots = function(data) {
  cat('\n\n### ', data, '\n')
  data_tmp = get(data)
  p = ggplot(data_tmp, aes(x = year, y = ratio)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", color =     "black", fill = "white") + ylab("Ratio") + xlab("Year") + theme_grey(base_size = 10)
  print(p)
}
pwalk(list(data_files), print_attr_plots)
```
````

This is my result:
[image]

Instead, I want the section headers and plots to alternate.
This code actually works in R-Markdown but strangely it does not in Quarto. Please help.

Comment: It's likely due to the `label` and `fig-cap`. Removing them makes it work

Comment: @AdroMine Thanks! This worked. This is quite an odd behaviour. I tested it as well and I can save at least the label if I put it next to "r" in the curly brackets.
If you write it down as a solution, I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of Quarto putting the figures together is because of that special `fig-` prefixed label and not because you are using `fig-cap`. Your intended approach would work if you had used either a simple label (like `label: test`, i.e. not `fig-` prefixed) or no label at all and `fig-cap`.

So the following works as intended (almost!!!),

Note that, I have used a list structure in `fig-cap` so that three plots have different captions.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| fig-cap: 
#|    - "Attribute in time in test1"
#|    - "Attribute in time in test2"
#|    - "Attribute in time in test3"
#| results: "asis"
#| message: false
#| echo: false

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
data_files = c(
  "test1",
  "test2",
  "test3"
)
set.seed(176)
test1 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))
test2 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))
test3 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))

print_attr_plots = function(data) {
  cat('\n\n### ', data, '\n')
  data_tmp = get(data)
  p = ggplot(data_tmp, aes(x = year, y = ratio)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "white") + 
      ylab("Ratio") + xlab("Year") + 
      theme_grey(base_size = 10)
  
  print(p)
}

walk(data_files, print_attr_plots)
```
````

[rendered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZoeo.png)

But the above approach is not quite enough (in my opinion). Because if you look at the output, you would see there are no `Figure` prefix in the captions and since you are not using a label, you can not refer to these figures.

So to solve this completely, you may want to use `[Figure Divs](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#figure-divs),

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
keep-md: true
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| results: "asis"
#| message: false

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
data_files = c(
  "test1",
  "test2",
  "test3"
)
set.seed(176)
test1 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))
test2 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))
test3 = data.frame(year = 1991:2010, ratio = runif(20, 0, 1))

print_attr_plots = function(data) {
  cat('\n\n### ', data, '\n')
  data_tmp = get(data)
  p = ggplot(data_tmp, aes(x = year, y = ratio)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", color =     "black", fill = "white") + ylab("Ratio") + xlab("Year") + theme_grey(base_size = 10)
  
  div_label <- paste0("#fig-", data)
  cat("\n::: {", div_label, "}\n", sep="")
  print(p)
  cat("\n\nAttribute in time in ", data, "\n", sep="")
  cat("\n:::\n")
}

walk(data_files, print_attr_plots)
```

check the plots @fig-test1, @fig-test2, @fig-test3
````

Here a separate Figure-Divb with id (which you can use in cross-referencing) and a caption is being created for each figure. Check out the linked documentation to know details about Figure-Divs.

[rendered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFV8Q.png)

Comment: Thanks :) This was a very full and inclusive answer!

Comment: The `qreport` R package has some related functions.